# MySql - What happens when i update with 'and'

Tags: mysql

I ran...

```
update TABLE set COLUMN1='XXX' and  COLUMN2='YYY' where ID=9999;
```

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Correct Query:

```
update TABLE set COLUMN1='XXX' , COLUMN2='YYY' where ID=9999;
```

Why MYSQL didnt throw any error?

Comment: If you run the above query, then you might get "error" as I got error in my test just now, but possible explanation as I understand is that, it try to evaluate the `'XXX' and COlumnd2='YYY'` into a logic value and than set Column1 as 1. Try it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked it and it looks like MySQL treats

> 'XXX' and  COLUMN2='YYY'

like expression. So it compares values of COLUMN2 and 'YYY', gets boolean result and performs 'XXX' AND that result, so you probably get 0 in COLUMN1 in the end since 'XXX' is not DOUBLE/INTEGER/BOOLEAN. COLUMN2 will be left unchanged.

This way this query is not erroneous, it just does not what you expected.

Comment: You will not "probably get 0".  You will always get "0".  The comparison `and` is going to convert both sides to a boolean/integer and `'XXX'` is converted to `0`.  You might get a different result with `'123xxx'`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right with textual values, but in case the first column was numerical there won't even be a warning!